# Every Brownian Motion is the result of Levy's Construction

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, brownian-motion

I want to show that any Brownian Motion $(B(t))$ on a Probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{A},\mathbb{P})$ is the a.s. result of a Levy's Construction, i.e. interpolation using a sequence of independent normally distributed random variables $\{Z_d\}_{d\in \mathcal{D}}$ with mean $0$ and variance $1$ where $\mathcal{D} = \{\text{dyadic numbers}\} = \{2^{-n}k: 1\leq k \leq 2^n,n\geq 1\}$. **I think this is true but I would like to have this verified.**

**My attempted proof:**

We use notation from the book Brownian Motion by Mörters and Peres. Let $\mathcal{D}_n = \{k2^{-n}: 1\leq k \leq 2^n\}$ and let $(\tilde{B}(t))$ be a Brownian Motion attained via Levy's construction using $\{\tilde{Z}_d\}_{d\in \mathcal{D}}$, where $\{\tilde{Z}_d\}_{d\in \mathcal{D}}$ are independent random variables with Gaussian distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1$. So that for $d\in \mathcal{D}_n$

$$\tilde B_n(d) = \sum_{i=0}^{n}\tilde F_i(d) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\tilde F_i(d)$$
where for $n>1$
$$\tilde F_n(t) = \begin{cases}2^{-(n+1)/2}\tilde Z_t& \text{ for $t\in \mathcal{D}_n\setminus \mathcal{D}_{n-1}$} \\
0& \text{ for $t\in \mathcal{D}_{n-1}$} \\
\text{linear interpolation between}\end{cases}$$
and $\tilde F_0(t) = t\tilde Z_1$.

Then
$$\tilde B(d) = \frac{\tilde B(d-2^{-n})+\tilde B(d+2^{-n})}{2}+\frac{\tilde Z_d}{2^{(n+1)/2}}$$ and hence for every $n$ there is a $2^n\times 2^n$ invertible matrix $A_n$ such that

\begin{equation*}
   \begin{pmatrix}
    \tilde{Z}_{d_1} \\
    \tilde{Z}_{d_2} \\
    \vdots \\
    \tilde{Z}_{d_{2^n}}
   \end{pmatrix} = A_n \begin{pmatrix}\tilde{B}_{d_1} \\
    \tilde{B}_{d_2} \\
    \vdots \\
    \tilde{B}_{d_{2^n}}
   \end{pmatrix}.
  \end{equation*}
where $d_k = k2^{-n}$ and where for any $m\leq n$ and $d_k\in \mathcal{D}_m$ the random variable $\tilde{Z}_{d_k}$ only depends on those $\tilde{B}_d$ where $d\in \mathcal{D}_m$. If we set
\begin{equation*}
    \tilde{X} := \begin{pmatrix}\tilde{B}_{d_1} \\
    \tilde{B}_{d_2} \\
    \vdots \\
    \tilde{B}_{d_{2^n}}
   \end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and } \quad X:= \begin{pmatrix}{B}_{d_1} \\
    {B}_{d_2} \\
    \vdots \\
    {B}_{d_{2^n}}
   \end{pmatrix}
  \end{equation*}
then we can define $A_nX = Z$. And since $\mathbb{P}_{X} = \tilde{\mathbb{P}}_{\tilde{X}}$ and $Z$ is a Gaussian random vector we conclude that the entries of $Z$ are independent with normal distributions with mean $0$ and variance $1$. Furthermore $X = A_n^{-1}Z$ and hence the Levy construction attained from $Z$ at step $n$ i.e.
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}F_i(d) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}F_i(d)$$
where we let $F_i$ be constructed as $\tilde F_i$ but changing $Z_t$ for $\tilde{Z}_t$, agrees with the Brownian Motion $(B(t))$ at all dyadic rationals of order less than $2^{-n}$: $\mathcal{D}_n$. Since $(B(t))$ are continuous a.s. the limit of the interpolation obtained via the Levy construction is precisely $(B(t))$.

Is there anything subtle I'm missing here?

The reason I wan't to have this result is that it is sometimes easier to prove a result about Brownian Motions as the limit of Levys Construction.

Comment: I don't see neither a specific statement nor a valid argument here. For example: "Hence the Levy construction attained from $Z$ at step $n$ agrees with the Brownian Motion $(B(t))$ at all dyadic rationals of order less than $2^{−n}$: $D_n$". What is the "Levy construction attained from $Z$"? Or "the limit is precisely $(B(t))$". Limit of what?

Comment: Ok yes I was not very precise in that statement I willclarify

Comment: Seems ok now. By the way, the continuity of Browian motion is often proved using the Levy construction, and here you use the continuity. So be careful not to get circular reasoning at some point.